# Unable to update protected property - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to update the `'status'` column of a row in my database.

The data is going through okay, e.g. when I `dd($request->status)` I get the correct update.

But, when I try and assign this to a protected property, it returns `201`, but it hasn't updated the row in the database.

I've used `json_encode()` and `json_decode()` to access the properties and when I `dd()` the object, the property has been updated, it just isn't making it to the database somehow.

Update function in my controller:

```
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $offer = Offer::where('id', $id)->first();

        $offer = json_encode($offer);
        $offer = json_decode($offer);

        $offer->status = $request->get('status');

        dd($offer);

        return response()->json('Status updated', 201);
    }
```

`dd($offer)` result:

```
{#281
  +"id": 32
  +"user_id": 35
  +"user_email": "test@bigeights.com"
  +"display_name": "333"
  +"item_id": 1
  +"item_name": "Glass Item"
  +"item_category": "glass"
  +"offer_price": "333"
  +"status": "accepted"
  +"created_at": "2020-04-28 03:41:37"
}
```

`Offer` model:

```
class Offer extends Model
{
    protected $table = "offers";
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

I have no experience with protected properties but I'm assuming that's why this is happening. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: why are you encoding and decoding your $offer ?

Comment: To access the ```'status'``` property. Otherwise, I get this:

Comment: It's too long for me to post but basically it returns the object nested in a bunch of data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to save the `$offer` object to persist to the database after altering the status:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $offer = Offer::where('id', $id)->first();

        $offer->status = $request->get('status');

        $offer->save();

        return response()->json('Status updated', 201);
    }
```

Comment: Okay, I can't believe I missed that, but now I get this error: ```message: "Call to undefined method stdClass::save()"```.

Comment: That's because you are using json. Those lines can be removed. See my edited answer.

P.S. Best practice would be to validate the status data before assigning it to the model.

Comment: Validate with ```if ($request->get('status'))...```?

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by @AlexW before me, you need to save the `$offer` model, otherwise the status won't be updated in the database:

```
$offer->save();
```